# Why does Illustrator's font selector tool behave like this?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Consider these 2 screenshots:

[image]

[image]

As you can see the **Character** is sometime *expanded*, but sometimes it is *collapsed*, which waste's 1-2 seconds *(because you have to click the label and then the font window opens)*. Really irritating.

Why does it behave like this and is there any way to expand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface auto-adjusts based on the screen size/resolution and current panel setup.

Comment: I read it 3-4 times. Couldn't alter the view of my layout. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: Ok. What is your screen size and resolution seen in the 2 images ?

Comment: Actually both are 2 projects. I opened them in different tabs in Illustrator. So I guess screen resolution would be same for both? Also, my PC is 1920x1080.

Comment: Also, when I resized Illustrator window a bit smaller, the problem occurred.

Comment: Your problem also happens on my computer, but ONLY when i resize the actual Illustrator window. The tools get minimized on a smaller window size, smaller screen size, etc. It's always been like that. Same thing happens in Photoshop by the way.

Comment: This might be useful https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/indesign-and-illustrator-ui-too-small/td-p/9722830